# Adding SVGs in HTML Elements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

I have an SVG that I want to add in every div displayed on the screen using a for loop.
SVG:

```html
   <div class='cart'>
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" version="1.1" width="256" height="256" viewBox="0 0 256 256" xml:space="preserve">

<defs>
</defs>
<g style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(1.4065934065934016 1.4065934065934016) scale(2.81 2.81)" >
    <path d="M 73.713 65.44 H 27.689 c -3.566 0 -6.377 -2.578 -6.686 -6.13 c -0.21 -2.426 0.807 -4.605 2.592 -5.939 L 16.381 21.07 c -0.199 -0.889 0.017 -1.819 0.586 -2.53 s 1.431 -1.124 2.341 -1.124 H 87 c 0.972 0 1.884 0.471 2.446 1.263 c 0.563 0.792 0.706 1.808 0.386 2.725 l -7.798 22.344 c -1.091 3.13 -3.798 5.429 -7.063 5.999 l -47.389 8.281 c -0.011 0.001 -0.021 0.003 -0.032 0.005 c -0.228 0.04 -0.623 0.126 -0.568 0.759 c 0.056 0.648 0.48 0.648 0.708 0.648 h 46.024 c 1.657 0 3 1.343 3 3 S 75.37 65.44 73.713 65.44 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round" />
    <circle cx="28.25" cy="75.8" r="6.5" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="  matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) "/>
    <circle cx="68.28999999999999" cy="75.8" r="6.5" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="  matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) "/>
    <path d="M 19.306 23.417 c -1.374 0 -2.613 -0.95 -2.925 -2.347 l -1.375 -6.155 c -0.554 -2.48 -2.716 -4.212 -5.258 -4.212 H 3 c -1.657 0 -3 -1.343 -3 -3 s 1.343 -3 3 -3 h 6.749 c 5.372 0 9.942 3.662 11.113 8.904 l 1.375 6.155 c 0.361 1.617 -0.657 3.221 -2.274 3.582 C 19.742 23.393 19.522 23.417 19.306 23.417 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round" />
</g>
</svg>
</div>
```

```
let cartSVG = document.querySelector('.cart');
for (let i =0; i < 10; i++) {
 var productPriceDisplay = document.createElement('div');
 productPriceDisplay.setAttribute('class', 'productPrice');
 productPriceDisplay.appendChild(cartSVG);

}
```

So I first create this element in HTML and using CSS , display it to none, so that users can't see it on screen.
Then, I use Javascript to get it's ID and append it to the all the divs using a for loop but that only adds it to the last div only.

I can't think of anything other than this method nor did I found any to display an SVG like this.

Comment: Yup, Now it works fine

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From MDN documentation on [`Node.appendChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):
*"If the given child is a reference to an existing node in the document, appendChild() **moves it from its current position to the new position**."*

In your code, you have one instance of `cartSVG`, so every time you try appending it to a new `productPriceDisplay`, it actually just moves the SVG from the previous div. As a result, at the end of your for loop, the SVG will only be on the last div.

The solution is to clone your SVG each time you want to add it to a new div using [`Node.cloneNode()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/cloneNode). So your JavaScript should look something like this:

```js
let cartSVG = document.querySelector('.cart');
for (let i =0; i < 10; i++) {
  var productPriceDisplay = document.createElement('div');
  productPriceDisplay.setAttribute('class', 'productPrice');
  productPriceDisplay.appendChild(cartSVG.cloneNode(true));
}
```

Comment: Note: You are not using the ``appendChild`` return value, so ``append`` is enough (and more powerful, since it accepts multiple elements) rather unused by older developers, because it wasn't available in IE11

Answer (score 0):

Or the modern way, Web Components are supported in every modern browser:

```js
customElements.define("svg-cart-icon", class extends HTMLElement {
  connectedCallback() {
    this.innerHTML = `<svg width="120" height="120" viewBox="0 0 256 256">
<g style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 0; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="translate(1.4065934065934016 1.4065934065934016) scale(2.81 2.81)" >
    <path d="M 73.713 65.44 H 27.689 c -3.566 0 -6.377 -2.578 -6.686 -6.13 c -0.21 -2.426 0.807 -4.605 2.592 -5.939 L 16.381 21.07 c -0.199 -0.889 0.017 -1.819 0.586 -2.53 s 1.431 -1.124 2.341 -1.124 H 87 c 0.972 0 1.884 0.471 2.446 1.263 c 0.563 0.792 0.706 1.808 0.386 2.725 l -7.798 22.344 c -1.091 3.13 -3.798 5.429 -7.063 5.999 l -47.389 8.281 c -0.011 0.001 -0.021 0.003 -0.032 0.005 c -0.228 0.04 -0.623 0.126 -0.568 0.759 c 0.056 0.648 0.48 0.648 0.708 0.648 h 46.024 c 1.657 0 3 1.343 3 3 S 75.37 65.44 73.713 65.44 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round" />
    <circle cx="28.25" cy="75.8" r="6.5" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="  matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) "/>
    <circle cx="68.28999999999999" cy="75.8" r="6.5" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform="  matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) "/>
    <path d="M 19.306 23.417 c -1.374 0 -2.613 -0.95 -2.925 -2.347 l -1.375 -6.155 c -0.554 -2.48 -2.716 -4.212 -5.258 -4.212 H 3 c -1.657 0 -3 -1.343 -3 -3 s 1.343 -3 3 -3 h 6.749 c 5.372 0 9.942 3.662 11.113 8.904 l 1.375 6.155 c 0.361 1.617 -0.657 3.221 -2.274 3.582 C 19.742 23.393 19.522 23.417 19.306 23.417 z" style="stroke: none; stroke-width: 1; stroke-dasharray: none; stroke-linecap: butt; stroke-linejoin: miter; stroke-miterlimit: 10; fill: currentcolor; fill-rule: nonzero; opacity: 1;" transform=" matrix(1 0 0 1 0 0) " stroke-linecap="round" />
</g>
</svg>`
  }
})
```

```html
<svg-cart-icon></svg-cart-icon>
<svg-cart-icon></svg-cart-icon>
<svg-cart-icon></svg-cart-icon>
```